# iOS - pushViewController:animated: doesn't push a table view properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` and a `HomeTabController`.

What I want to do is to push a `UITableViewController` when I click a button on the view.

However, there did show an animation but no table view presented.

Just to make it clearer, here I have two screenshots.

[image]

[image]

## part of my code

```
@implementation HomeTabController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.title = @"SCUxCHG";
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target = self;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action = @selector(didClickSearchBtn:);
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    _cMainSearchTableViewController = [[HomeTabSearchTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:_cMainSearchTableViewController];

-(IBAction)didClickSearchBtn:(id)sender
{
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_cMainSearchTableViewController animated:YES];
}
@end
```

**MainSearchTableViewController.m**

```
@interface HomeTabSearchTableViewController (){
    UISearchController* _cSearchController;
    UITableViewController* _cSearchResultTableViewController;
    NSArray* _allProductsIdsAndNamesPairs;
    NSMutableArray* _filteredProducts;
}
@end

@implementation HomeTabSearchTableViewController


-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _cSearchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:_cSearchResultTableViewController];
    [self addChildViewController:_cSearchController];
    [_cSearchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _cSearchController.searchBar;
    [_cSearchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
    [self.tableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.view);
        make.top.equalTo(self.view);
        make.width.mas_equalTo(self.view);
        make.height.equalTo(self.view);
    }];

    _cSearchResultTableViewController.tableView.delegate = self;
    _cSearchResultTableViewController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self getData];
}

- (void)getData{
    [ProductModel getAllProductsIdsAndNamesDictionarySuccess:^(BOOL result, NSString* message, NSArray* allProductsIdsAndNamesPaires){
        if (!result) {
            _allProductsIdsAndNamesPairs = allProductsIdsAndNamesPaires;
            NSLog(@"%@", _allProductsIdsAndNamesPairs);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@", message);
        }
    }failure:^(NSError* error){
    }];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        if (!_cSearchController.active) {
            return 0;
        }else{
            return _filteredProducts.count;
        }
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString* identifier = @"HomeTabMainSearchTableView";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"搜索 %@", _cSearchController.searchBar.text];
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [_filteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UISearchResultUpdating

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    [_filteredProducts removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", _cSearchController.searchBar.text];

    _filteredProducts = [[_allProductsIdsAndNamesPairs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate] mutableCopy];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_cSearchResultTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
@end
```

You can see from the code that I'm implementing a `UISearchController` with a `UITableView`.

What might be the problem?

There was no error message in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you add your table view vc as the child view controller and then push it into navigation controller. that's wrong. Try remove

```
  [self addChildViewController:_cMainSearchTableViewController];
```

from your `viewDidLoad` method. 
Also, try to load your tableView from xib, or storyboard, instead of [[alloc] init]. From existing code - you push vc with zero frame.
 For example (for xib):

```
HomeTabSearchTableViewController *vc = [[HomeTabSearchTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([HomeTabSearchTableViewController class]) bundle:nil];
```

for storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View controller storyboard id"];
```

UPDATE:

if you don't use storyboard or xib, set up the frame of your view after initialisation, and then push into navigation stack.

Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why the table view vc cannot be a child view controller? And I don't use xib or storyboard actually. I use code to control UI. Also, I've tried to overwrite the `init` method of the table view vc but it doesn't help?

Comment: @penguin-penpen, actually, you have navigation view controller. You push into it table VC. it's unnecessary to add it as ChildVC. Did you try to set the frame? try initWithFrame: method

Comment: You're right. `self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:];` works. I thought the `init` method would automatically initialize the view which sized the screen bound.

Comment: @penguin-penpen, that's good :) with default init method your view will have CGRectZero by default